# Showing that $P(x)=x^{p-1}-1+pQ(x)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, proof-writing

This comes from a problem from Imo math notes on algebraic extensions.

One needs to show that $P(x)=(x+1)(x+2) \dots (x+p-1) = P(x)=x^{p-1}-1+pQ(x)$, where $p$ is prime and $Q(x)$ a polynomial with integer coefficients.

I understand the rest of the solution, but not this part. It's easy to see why $p$ does not divide the first or last coefficients of the polynomial, but I can't see why $p$ divides the rest. I tried Vieta's formulas and induction, both without success.

Can anyone help show me how to prove this?

Comment: Do you want us to prove that the constant term is $\equiv -1 \pmod p$ or have you done that already?

Comment: @NobleMushtak No, that the constant term $ \equiv -1 (\mod p)$ follows from Wilson's theorem, so I don't need help with that. I need help showing that $p$ divides the rest of the coefficients of the polynomial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A(x)=(x+1)(x+2)\cdots (x+p-1)$ and let $B(x)=x^{p-1}-1$. Note that every $x$ from $1$ to $p-1$ is a root of $A(x)-B(x)$, and $A(x)-B(x)$ has degree $\lt p-1$. For the roots of $A(x)$ in the $p$-element field are $-1$ to $-(p-1)$, which is $1$ to $p-1$ in reverse order. And the fact that every non-zero element of the field $\Bbb{F}_p$ is a root of $B(x)$ follows from Fermat's Theorem.

But in a field, a polynomial of degree $d$ has at most $d$ roots. So $A(x)-B(x)$ is the zero polynomial, and therefore its coefficients are all divisible by $p$.